# Adding functions to content navigation drawer

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to add functions to my kivymd navigation drawer but i cant find a way to do it. i want the items to pen defferent pages. an example is the settings item should open the settings page when clicked. i an using the new updated kivymd version 0.103.0

this is an example code

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty



class TestNavigationDrawer(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def on_start(self):
        icons_item = {
            "folder": "My files",
            "account-multiple": "Shared with me",
            "star": "Starred",
            "history": "Recent",
            "checkbox-marked": "Shared with me",
            "upload": "Upload",
        }
        for icon_name in icons_item.keys():
            self.root.ids.content_drawer.ids.md_list.add_widget(
                ItemDrawer(icon=icon_name, text=icons_item[icon_name])
            )
```

Comment: Use on_release to set an action. In last string ItemDrawer(icon=icon_name, text=icons_item[icon_name], on_release=...)

Answer (score 0):

As Lothric said, you need to add an 'on_release' attribute to the ItemDrawer instantiation. The value of this attribute should be whatever function you want called when the button is pressed (usually lambda if using a method callback).

Not that you asked, but KivyMD has a "kitchensink" demo app in GitLab that serves to demonstrate the functionality of some of their widgets. [Here's the link](https://gitlab.com/kivymd/KivyMD/blob/master/demos/kitchen_sink/main.py)

Answer (score 0):

The other way is to simply remove method on_start() from class TestNavigationDrawer()
and write code in .kv ScrollView file for switching  from one page to other.
I just started learning so my code may not be optimal but its full fill the requirement mentioned in question.
i.e. I'm pasting complete code

use sample code as provided below:

main.py

```
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.theming import ThemableBehavior
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineIconListItem, MDList
from kivymd.theming import  ThemeManager

class ContentNavigationDrawer(BoxLayout):
    screen_manager = ObjectProperty()
    nav_drawer = ObjectProperty()


class DrawerList(ThemableBehavior, MDList):
    def set_color_item(self, instance_item):
        '''Called when tap on a menu item.'''
        # Set the color of the icon and text for the menu item.
        for item in self.children:
            if item.text_color == self.theme_cls.primary_color:
                item.text_color = self.theme_cls.text_color
                break
        instance_item.text_color = self.theme_cls.primary_color


class ItemDrawer(OneLineIconListItem):
    icon = StringProperty()


class DrawerList(ThemableBehavior, MDList):
    def set_color_item(self, instance_item):
        """Called when tap on a menu item."""

        # Set the color of the icon and text for the menu item.
            for item in self.children:
                if item.text_color == self.theme_cls.primary_color:
                item.text_color = self.theme_cls.text_color
                break
        instance_item.text_color = self.theme_cls.primary_color



#GUI = Builder.load_file(r"C:\Users\main.kv")
class MainApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.theme_cls = ThemeManager()

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Green"
        self.theme_cls.primary_hue = "200"
        #return GUI


MainApp().run()
```

main.kv

```
#: include navigationdrawer.kv

Screen:
    MDToolbar:
        id: toolbar
        pos_hint: {"top": 1}
        elevation: 10
        title: "Anything"
        left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer.toggle_nav_drawer()]]

    NavigationLayout:
        x: toolbar.height

        ScreenManager:
            id: screen_manager

            Screen:
                name: "scr 0"
                MDLabel:
                    text: "Screen 0"
                    halign: "center"

            Screen:
                name: "scr 1"
                MDLabel:
                    text: "Screen 1"
                    halign: "center"
            Screen:
                name: "scr 2"
                MDLabel:
                    text: "Screen 2"
                    halign: "center"


        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer
            ContentNavigationDrawer:
                screen_manager: screen_manager
                nav_drawer: nav_drawer
```

navigationdrawer.kv

```
<ItemDrawer>:
    theme_text_color: "Custom"
    on_release:
        print("HI IM Pringint" )
        self.parent.set_color_item(self)

    IconLeftWidget:
        id: icon
        icon: root.icon
        theme_text_color: "Custom"
        text_color: root.text_color


<ContentNavigationDrawer>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    padding: "8dp"
    spacing: "8dp"

    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: "left"
        size_hint_y: None
        height: avatar.height

       Image:
            id: avatar
            #size_hint: None, None
            #size: "300dp", "300dp"
            source: "img/tiger.jpg"

    MDLabel:
        text: "All Starts Here!"
        font_style: "Button"
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.texture_size[1]

    MDLabel:
        text: "Adding green energy to your life..."
        font_style: "Caption"
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.texture_size[1]

    ScrollView:

#        DrawerList:
#            id: md_list

        MDList:
            id: md_list
            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Screen 1"
                on_press:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                    root.screen_manager.current = "scr 1"

            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Screen 2"
                on_press:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                    root.screen_manager.current = "scr 2"
```

Thank you , hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

## Another solution

I'm an absolute beginner and my solution is maybe not the best or even right. But it is working for me.

My kivy, kivymd and python versions:

Name: Kivy
Version: 2.0.0

Name: kivymd
Version: 0.104.1

Python 3.8.5

**main.py**

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ListProperty

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.theming import ThemableBehavior
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineIconListItem, MDList


class NavigationDrawer(BoxLayout):
    pass


class ContentNavigationDrawer(BoxLayout):
    pass


class ItemDrawer(OneLineIconListItem):
    icon = StringProperty()
    text_color = ListProperty((0, 0, 0, 1))


class DrawerList(ThemableBehavior, MDList):
    def set_color_item(self, instance_item):
        """Called when tap on a menu item."""

        # Set the color of the icon and text for the menu item.
        for item in self.children:
            if item.text_color == self.theme_cls.primary_color:
                item.text_color = self.theme_cls.text_color
                break
        instance_item.text_color = self.theme_cls.primary_color


class TestNavigationDrawer(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file('main.kv')

    def on_start(self):
        icons_item = {
            "home": "Home",
            "folder": "My files",
            "account-multiple": "Shared with me",
            "star": "Starred",
            "history": "Recent",
            "checkbox-marked": "Shared with others",
            "upload": "Upload",
        }
        for icon_name in icons_item.keys():
            self.root.ids.content_drawer.ids.md_list.add_widget(
                ItemDrawer(icon=icon_name, text=icons_item[icon_name])
            )


TestNavigationDrawer().run()
```

**main.kv**

```
# Menu item in the DrawerList list.
<ItemDrawer>:
    theme_text_color: "Custom"
    # on_press: self.parent.set_color_item(self)
    on_press:
        app.root.ids.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
        app.root.ids.screen_manager.current = self.text.lower()
    

    IconLeftWidget:
        id: icon
        icon: root.icon
        theme_text_color: "Custom"
        text_color: root.text_color


<ContentNavigationDrawer>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    padding: "8dp"
    spacing: "8dp"

    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: "left"
        size_hint_y: None
        height: avatar.height

        Image:
            id: avatar
            size_hint: None, None
            size: "56dp", "56dp"
            source: "data/logo/kivy-icon-256.png"

    MDLabel:
        text: "KivyMD library"
        font_style: "Button"
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.texture_size[1]

    MDLabel:
        text: "kivydevelopment@gmail.com"
        font_style: "Caption"
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.texture_size[1]

    ScrollView:

        DrawerList:
            id: md_list


<NavigationDrawer>:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    MDToolbar:
        title: "Navigation Drawer"
        elevation: 10
        left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: app.root.ids.nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]

    Widget:


Screen:

    NavigationLayout:

        ScreenManager:
            id: screen_manager

            Screen:
                name: "home"
                NavigationDrawer:

                BoxLayout:
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Home"
                        halign: "center"

            Screen:
                name: "my files"
                NavigationDrawer:

                BoxLayout:
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "My Files"
                        halign: "center"

            Screen:
                name: "shared with me"
                NavigationDrawer:

                BoxLayout:
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Shared with me"
                        halign: "center"

            Screen:
                name: "starred"
                NavigationDrawer:

                BoxLayout:
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Starred"
                        halign: "center"

            Screen:
                name: "recent"
                NavigationDrawer:

                BoxLayout:
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Recent"
                        halign: "center"

            Screen:
                name: "shared with others"
                NavigationDrawer:

                BoxLayout:
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Shared with others"
                        halign: "center"

            Screen:
                name: "upload"
                NavigationDrawer:

                BoxLayout:
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Upload"
                        halign: "center"


        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer

            ContentNavigationDrawer:
                id: content_drawer
```

Answer (score 0):

A short example how to add function to content;

```
# .py file
class ItemDrawer(OneLineIconListItem):
    icon = StringProperty()

    def upload(self):
        if self.icon == "upload":
            print("Item uploaded")

# .kv file
<ItemDrawer>:
    on_release: root.upload()
```